# Не отображаются данные в FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android

Хотела прикрутить себе галерею [отсюда](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)
Но что-то, видимо, делала не так (правда, иконки-кружочки внизу исправно показываются и их даже можно листать). Сначала пыталась сделать галерею фотографий, ничего не отображалось, думала, дело в них. Но никакие данные, **совсем никакие**, не отображаются. Я пробовала подключать другие лэйауты, делать их вручную-программно, ничего не помогает. При этом логи исправно пишут, что весь код работает нормально и везде проходит.
Привожу много много кода:

```
public class Activity_HotelFoto extends FragmentActivity {
ArrayList<Map<String,Object>> images;
ViewPager pager;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hotelfoto);
            FotoPagerAdapter adap = new FotoPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),images, getLayoutInflater());
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        //pager = new ViewPager(this);
        pager.setAdapter(adap);
        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
            public void onPageSelected(int pos) {
                Log.d(TAG,"page selected " + pos);
                pager.setCurrentItem(pos);
            }
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                Log.d(TAG,"page scrolled");
            }
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                Log.d(TAG,"page scroll state changed");
            }
        });

        CirclePageIndicator indicator = (CirclePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        //indicator = new CirclePageIndicator(this);
        indicator.setViewPager(pager);
        final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        indicator.setBackgroundColor(0xFFCCCCCC);
        indicator.setRadius(10 * density);
        indicator.setPageColor(0x880000FF);
        indicator.setFillColor(0xFF888888);
        indicator.setStrokeColor(0xFF000000);
        indicator.setStrokeWidth(2 * density);
}
```

activity_hotelfoto.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical">
     <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    <com.volha.samotravel.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

FotoPagerAdapter:

```
class FotoPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements IconPagerAdapter {

    private final String TAG = "FotoPagerAdapter";
    ArrayList<Map<String,Object>> items = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    int count;
    public FotoPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<Map<String,Object>> pages,  LayoutInflater inflater){
        super(fm);
        this.items = pages;
        this.inflater = inflater;
        this.count = pages.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Log.d(TAG,position + ") " + items.get(position).get("src"));
        return Fragment_HotelFoto.newInstance(items.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object){
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(View arg0){
    }
    public int getIconResId(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Тот самый Fragment_HotelFoto, содержимое которого не показывается, при этом логи из него исправно пишутся:

```
public class Fragment_HotelFoto extends Fragment{

    private final String TAG = "Fragmnet_HotelFoto";

    private static ImageLoader imageLoader;
    ArrayList<Map<String,Object>> images;
    private Map<String,Object> item;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState){

       View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.no_result, null);
       Log.d(TAG,"item" + item.get("src"));
       return v;
    }
    public static Fragment newInstance(Map<String, Object> map) {
        Fragment_HotelFoto frag = new Fragment_HotelFoto();
        frag.item = map;
        return frag;
    }
}
```

И последнее, no_result.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Нет результатов"
    android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/tvNoResult"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Activity_HotelFoto extends FragmentActivity {
ArrayList<Map<String,Object>> images;
ViewPager pager;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hotelfoto);
            FotoPagerAdapter adap = new FotoPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),images, getLayoutInflater());
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
```

где ты заполняешь и определяешь images ?

Comment: Я этот код опустила... Там было много не значимого. 
К тому же в упрощенном варианте они не отображаются в Fragment_HotelFoto - там лэйаут с одним статичным textView. Хотя в логах данные из images выходят.

Comment: в адаптер надо передать фрагменты которые, будут отрисованы, если тебе надо просто сделать галерею картинок http://nostra13android.blogspot.com/2012/03/5-universal-image-loader-part-2.html - то это лучше вариант

Comment: Я передаю данные, просто не стала приводить тут этот код, в моей программе он есть, правда! И я и так использую загрузчик картинок от Ностры, вопрос-то не в этом. А в том, что совсем никакие данные не отображаются, хотя в Fragment_HotelFoto программа заходит.